# WKWebsiteDataStore.default() vs webView.configuration.websiteDataStore

Tags: xamarin.ios, webkit, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

What is the difference between the `WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore` and the one present in webview configuration instance - `Configuration.WebsiteDataStore`?

If i delete a specific cookie from `HttpCookieStore` by accessing the default websitedatastore, would that be in sync with `HttpCookieStore` present in `Configuration.WebsiteDataStore` when webview loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you pass a `WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()` (which is new every time) dataStore to your webview's configuration it will already have the `default` in there (which is shared and it's always the same).

You can check that yourself by running

```swift
webview.configuration.websiteDataStore == WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
```

And it will return true.

So everything is definitely in sync since they are the same instance.